# How do you configure Query Logging for Neo4j Community Edition 3.10 on OS X?

Tags: logging, neo4j, configuration, graph-databases

I am trying to configure Neo4j for query logging on Mac OS X.

I added the following lines to ~/Documents/Neo4j/.neo4j.conf

```
# Enable query logging with parameters
dbms.logs.query.enabled=true
dbms.logs.query.parameter_logging_enabled=true
```

which seemed to be what the directions called for. My DB is located in a different directory.

What am I doing wrong? I don't see any query logging nor do I see the query.log file appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query logging is an enterprise-edition-only feature. While that's not explicitly on the query logging docs page, it is noted on the [Logging](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/) page which is the parent to the query logging page.

If you use the Neo4j Desktop app, you will be granted an individual non-production enterprise license (with restrictions) and be able to spin up an enterprise edition instance which you can configure to log your queries.

Comment: ah ok, that clears that up... unfortunately. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: you should restart the neo4j after make changes in neo4j.conf file. Also, [according the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/), the file location of neo4j.conf file in OS X desktop installations is:

`${HOME}/Documents/Neo4j/neo4j.conf`

That is: without the dot before `neo4j.conf`.

Comment: thanks. I did try that earlier. No luck. I still do not see a query.log file.